# Effect of insulated high voltage wire to micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, high-voltage

I am investigating a home appliance product which is reported out of order. Having disassembled and checked, I found the power and ground pin of the micro-controller is shorted.

In this product, there is a high voltage ion generator  which will generate about 3 kV. The wire with the 3 kV potential has a 6 kV DC rated insulation jacket. This wire can be very close to the micro-controller (and the electronic board) inside the product. I have done a 3.5 kV hi-pot test of this wire (supplying the voltage between the wire conductor and the insulator) and there is no current leakage.

Although there is no current leakage from the wire conductor to the outside of the wire, will the high potential of the wire damage the micro-controller (the micro-controller is working around 3.3 Vdc, so the potential difference between the wire conductor and the micro-controller can be 3 kV)?

Comment: Who knows what can happen? Having no leakage does not mean that the high voltage never discharges to the rest of the circuit. Having a wire with some kV run close to low-voltage electronics is asking for trouble in my book. If it cannot be avoided then use a coax type cable with a grounded shield so that the E-field stays inside the wire.

Comment: Have you checked if the power and ground pin are internaly or externaly shorted? What does shorted mean to you (0 Ohm)?

Comment: @A.R.C. The pins are internally shorted, and yes 0 Ohm.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes I have the same thought but I am lack of supporting. Could you share any reference related to the effect of the E-field to the low-voltage electronics? And if possible, is there any experiment that I can do to prove the problem? Thank you very much.